# Finding the latest record in each window - MariaDB/MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

In MariaDb 10.3, how to find the latest(based on timestamp) row for each window(or partition, I am not entirely clear on the terminology here)?

Consider the following table with data

| ItemID | Itemname | Value | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 22 | 2021-12-22 20:01:00 |
| 1 | A | 2 | 2021-12-22 15:09:44 |
| 1 | A | 3 | 2021-12-22 14:39:49 |
| 2 | B | 54 | 2021-12-22 12:46:37 |
| 2 | B | 23 | 2021-12-22 12:17:52 |
| 2 | B | 43 | 2021-12-22 11:19:11 |
| 1 | A | 23 | 2021-12-22 04:00:58 |
| 1 | A | 53 | 2021-12-22 03:00:58 |
| 3 | C | 21 | 2021-12-21 04:00:58 |
| 2 | B | 74 | 2021-12-21 04:06:58 |
| 2 | B | 36 | 2021-12-21 04:06:09 |
| 1 | A | 34 | 2021-12-21 03:08:09 |

Desired output

| ItemID | ItemName | Value | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 22 | 2021-12-22 20:01:00 |
| 2 | B | 54 | 2021-12-22 12:46:37 |
| 1 | A | 23 | 2021-12-22 04:00:58 |
| 3 | C | 21 | 2021-12-21 04:00:58 |
| 2 | B | 74 | 2021-12-21 04:06:58 |
| 1 | A | 34 | 2021-12-21 03:08:09 |

Comment: what constitutes a "dataset"?  the same ItemID and ItemName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query generates expected result

```
WITH ordered AS (
  SELECT 
    *, 
    LAG(`ItemID`) OVER (ORDER BY `Timestamp` DESC) AS LastItem
  FROM dataset
)
SELECT `ItemID`, `ItemName`, `Value`, `Timestamp`
FROM ordered
WHERE `ItemID` <> `LastItem` OR `LastItem` IS NULL
ORDER BY `Timestamp` DESC
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=36b51459484827bb6a4c4e171a7ead52)

Comment: Should perhaps explain why. :)